# android SQLite find whereclause by a parameter

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite class with two parameters: name and TimesOpened.

I want to update the TimesOpened, how can i find and update it in the sqlite without knowing the whereclause but only the name parameter?

Here is my SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "app_name";
public static final String KEY_OPENED = "app_opened";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favorite_apps";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="apps_table";
public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public Dbhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            KEY_OPENED + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

);
    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME }, null, null,
            null, null, KEY_NAME+ " ASC");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

The app automatically adds items to the database so i can't tell what is each item where clause but i can tell the name.

That's the code i'm trying to use now to update

```
    public void find_clause(String appname, int TimesOpened){
    database.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s=%s WHERE %s=%s",
            DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_OPENED,TimesOpened,KEY_NAME,appname));
}
```

I'm calling it here

```
     info.find_clause(foregroundTaskPackageName,sharedPrefs.getInt(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0) + 1);
```

foregroundTaskPackageName is the app_name and the "sharedPrefs.getInt(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0) + 1)" is the times_opened

When i'm getting the database back nothing seems to change and the log give me this `

```
07-07 20:54:21.093  21213-21253/com.assist.me E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: com.assist.me


07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: com.assist.me (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE apps_table SET app_opened=126 WHERE app_name=com.assist.me
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at com.pin.assistme.favorite_apps.find_clause(favorite_apps.java:30)
07-07 20:54:27.103  21213-21253/com.assist.me W/System.err﹕ at com.pin.assistme.services$ThreadDemo.run(services.java:127)
```

**com.assist.me is the package name of the app**
**update**
the correct code is

```
db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s='%s' WHERE %s='%s'", DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_OPENED,SET_TO_THIS,KEY_NAME,YOUR_NAME));
```

Comment: are you trying to update a single record only?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Either you don't quite understand databases, or you aren't being clear.  What do you mean by an SQLite class?  Do you mean a class representing data you want to store in a database?  And how can you not know a where clause-  you write a where clause to limit the results of a query.  You don't ever need to know one, just know how to write one.

Comment: I'm only trying to update the TimesOpened for the name

Comment: Choose the correct answer if it helped you. I told you from the start to quote appname but I guess you wanted to find it out by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s='%s' WHERE %s='%s'",
                DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_OPENED,SET_TO_THIS,KEY_NAME,YOUR_NAME));
```

Change SET_TO_THIS, to the value that you want to set the app_opened.

Change YOUR_NAME, to the value that you know (name parameter).

EDIT: 
Better yet use the update method:

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
content.put(KEY_OPENED, TimesOpened);

db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, content, KEY_NAME+"=?", new String[] {appname});
```

Comment: It says it cant resolve method rawQuery(java.lang.String)
Any ideas?

Comment: I've placed it like this
  public void find_clause(String appname, int TimesOpened){
        database.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s=%s WHERE %s=%s",
                DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_OPENED,appname,KEY_NAME,TimesOpened));
    }

Then called it in my service like this
                        info.find_clause(foregroundTaskPackageName,sharedPrefs.getInt(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0) + 1);
foregroundTaskPackageName is the app name string and the "sharedPrefs.getInt(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0) + 1)" is the times it been opened
After all that nothing seem to change

Comment: I think you misplaced appname and TimesOpened. Try switching them in place.

Comment: I found the error the log says: "E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column:"

Comment: Let's continue in the chat room: [Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56900/just-a-chat-room)

Comment: I can't, it says I must have 20 reputation to got in there

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows

the query what you are trying to execute is

```
       UPDATE apps_table SET app_opened=126 WHERE app_name=com.assist.me
```

the query should be

```
      UPDATE apps_table SET app_opened=126 WHERE app_name='com.assist.me'
```

Change your method accordingly to get the single quote for the app name and try